# Need to develop simple driver for general card ( transfer video ) - how to start ( windows )?

Tags: device-driver

I have some simple card that will be use to transfer video from webCam to the PC.

Now, i need to write a drive to this card and make sure that the video will be seen by some other application that i already wrote.

The card is not sit in the pc - so i using UBS to connect to the card that will be sit in some other 'box'.

I download the DDK - and i was reading about how to do it.

But now i don't know how to start.

Is there any code example and some good reference that i can learn to know how to start and how to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading some books about Windows driver development.  For example [this book](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/wdf/wdfbook.mspx)

There are sample drivers in the DDK.  The description of the sample driver is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561313%28VS.85%29.aspx)